# Sass don't get fonts and images in Laravel 8.1

Tags: laravel, sass, fonts, laravel-8, laravel-mix

Good afternoon.
I'm in troubles a few days ago because I can't load fonts and images that I have stored in public folder.

As you can see, i have a main.scss file that have some variables, font-faces and a mixin.

```css
$primaryGreen: #1e8b22;
$secondaryGreen: #0dee15;
$primaryRed: #962525;
$secondaryRed: #f50404;
$primaryGray: #333333;
$White: #ffffff;


$okGreen: #0dee15;
$errorRed: #f50404;
$alertYellow: #fffb00;
$hintBlue: #0064e7;

$whiteText: #ffffff;
$blackText: #000000;


@font-face {
        font-family: logoWhite;
        src: url('/public/assets/fonts/JFRocOut.eot') format('opentype');
};
        
@font-face {
        font-family: logoBlack;
        src: url('/public/assets/fonts/JFRocSol.TTF') format('truetype');
};
        
@font-face {
        font-family: titleFont;
        src: url('/public/assets/fonts/Boogaloo.ttf') format('truetype');
};
        
@font-face {
        font-family: textFont;
        src: url('/public/assets/fonts/Baloo2.ttf') format('truetype');
};


@mixin reset {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
}
```

Well, then I have a navbar.scss, where i call a font-face and an image via url, but they don't work.

```css
@import 'main';

body{
        @include reset;
}
#navbar{  
        height: 61px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: $primaryGray;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 2fr;
        
}

#logo{
        font-family: logoWhite;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        color: white;
}

#pageBody{
        width: screen;
        height: 100vh;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;

        background-image: url('/public/assets/images/Minulogo.png');
}
```

But fonts and images don't display.
[image: testpage]

If this helps, my webpack.mix.js is like this:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');


mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js');

mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css', {
    implementation: require('node-sass')
})
   .sass('resources/sass/navbar.scss', 'public/css', {
    implementation: require('node-sass')
})

   .sourceMaps();
```

And the packaje.json

```json
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.32.11",
        "sass-loader": "^11.0.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "node-sass": "^7.0.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything public should be in the public directory. The index page for is as well. Therefor you could try just `/fonts/JFRocOut.eot` as a path.

Comment: @SuperDJ well, I tried to put the route as you but then laravel don't reconignizes it.